# jQuery checking file extension not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

I want to upload a file, and I want to prevent the user from selecting files in the wrong format. So I am using a jQuery script to verify the file extension.

Here is the input

```
<input id="uploadCV" type="file" name="uploadCV" accept="application/pdf" />
```

Here is the jQuery script

```
if ($("#uploadCV").val().split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "PDF") 
{
     return true;
}
else{
     return false;
}
```

This code works just fine on Firefox, but in IE it wouldn't. This is because in IE the file name in `$("#uploadCV").val()` does not contains the extension, for instance it contains `\directory\filename` instead of `\directory\filename.pdf`.

Has anyone faced something like this before ? is there any workaround ?

Comment: I checked with IE8 and IE9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this with IE9, I've got no IE8 to test right now,
this function also considers the last dot, in your solution the extension would be wrong if the filename would contain dots like this.is.a.pdf.pdf

check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HN7Ww/1/

```
$('#sendMe').click(function() {
    var file = $("#uploadCV").val();
    if (file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('.') +1).toUpperCase() == "PDF") 
    {
         $('.result').html('valid');
    }
    else
    {
           $('.result').html('not valid');

    }
});
```

.

```
<input id="uploadCV" type="file" name="uploadCV" accept="application/pdf" />
<div class="result"></div>
<input type="button" id="sendMe" value="send" />
```

let me know if you need any further help

regards 
jan

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fileid').change(function (e) {
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    if(ext.toLowerCase() !== "pdf" )
    {
        alert("Only Pdf format supported");
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $('#fileid').replaceWith($('#').clone()); // This makes file selected to null in IE
      }
      else {
            $('#fileid').val("");
      }
    }

});
```

This will allow to display alert if you select non-pdf files and also clears the selection if you select non-pdf files.